# Why doesn't bash flag -e exit when a subshell fails?

Tags: bash

I'm a bit confused here. My goal here is to have the bash script exit with a non-zero exit code when any of the commands within the script fails. Using the -e flag, I assumed this would be the case, even when using subshells. Below is a simplified example:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

(false)

echo $?
echo "Line reached!"
```

Here is the output when ran:

```
[$]>Tests/Exec/continuous-integration.sh 
1
Line reached!
```

Bash version: 3.2.25 on CentOS

Comment: Is there any chance at all you can update your bash version, because this exact script works as intended in 4.1.5.  Perhaps it's your `false` version

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears as though this is related to your version of `bash`.  On machines that I have access to, bash version 3.1.17 and 3.2.39 exhibit this behaviour, bash 4.1.5 does not.

Although a bit ugly, a solution that works in both versions could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

(false) || exit $?

echo $?
echo "Line reached!"
```

There are some notes in the bash source changelog which related to bugs with the `set -e` option.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the digging, this was it! Thanks for the suggested answer, that's exactly what I will be doing.

Comment: Don't know what OS OP is on, but e.g. Mountain Lion still ships with bash 3, unfortunately.

Comment: Note that your workaround doesn't work when using with `export` : `export test=$(false) || exit $?`. You will have to assign the variable first then use `export`: `test=$(false) || exit $?; export test`

Comment: The suggested workaround for bash3 won't work, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365186/94687 . It would even cause a wrong behavior in bash4.

Comment: Something like this `bash -ec '(echo 1; false; echo 2); [ $? -eq 0 ]; echo 3'` must work as expected both in bash4 and bash3, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 16):

The `-e` option is for current shell, for sub-shell, functions, etc we use `-E`

form **man bash**

> **-E** If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment.

And for advanced users, a kind of strict mode we have which is:

```bash
# one line
set -Eeuo pipefail
```

- `-E` explained above
- `-e` exit immediately
- `-u` exit for unbound variable found
- `-o` set option
- `pipefail` exit if we had failure on a pipe

if you want to use strict-mode as a function

```bash
################################################################################
#
# bash strict mode
#
################################################################################
strict_mode(){
    set -T # inherit DEBUG and RETURN trap for functions
    set -C # prevent file overwrite by > &> <>
    set -E # inherit -e
    set -e # exit immediately on errors
    set -u # exit on not assigned variables
    set -o pipefail # exit on pipe failure
}
strict_mode;
```

Comment: so to be clear, you need to specify both `-E` `-e` in order to have the expected behavior. `-E` by itself does not make the shell exit on error

Comment: Does `E` support multiple, nested subshells?

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this behavior in bash version 3.2.51 on both SuSE 11.3 and Mac OS prior to El Capitan. Bash 3.2.57 on El Capitan has the "correct" behavior, ie like bash 4.

However, the workaround proposed above, adding "|| exit $?" after the subshell's closing paren, defeats the intent of the -e flag no matter what version of bash. From man bash:

> -e  Exit immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits 
>   with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is 
>   part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part
>   of the test in an if statement, part of a && or || list, ...

A subshell followed by "|| exit $?" apparently counts as a command list; and the bash -e flag will not apply to ANY command inside the subshell. Try it:

```
$ set -e
$ ( echo before the error; false; echo after the error, status $?; ) || echo after the subshell, status $?
before the error
after the error, status 1
$
```

Because the subshell is followed by ||, that "echo after the error" is run, even with set -e. Not only that, the subshell exits 0, because that "echo" ran. So "|| exit $?" would not even run the "exit".  Probably not what we wanted!

So far as I know, the following formula is compatible with bash versions whether they honor bash -e after subshell, or not. It even behaves correctly if the -e flag happens to be reset:

> Add the following line immediately after the closing parenthesis of every subshell in the bash script:

```
case $?/$- in ( 0/* ) ;; ( */*e* ) exit $? ;; esac # honor bash -e flag when subshell returns
```

Comment: Good point! Something like this `bash -ec '(echo 1; false; echo 2); [ $? -eq 0 ]; echo 3'` must work as expected both in bash4 and bash3.