# Using command substitution or similar, but still having script exit (using set -e)

Tags: bash

Bash doesn't seem to pass the "exit on error" environment flag into command substitution shells.

I am using a large number of command substitutions (to get around bash's lack of return values), but I'd still like the whole script to go down if something in the subshell fails.

So, for example:

```
set -e    

function do_internet {
    curl not.valid.address
}

answer=$(do_internet)
```

I'd like the script to stop there and then, and not continue.
(I hoped that setting -e would stop from having to put '|| die' on everything.

Am I doing something wrong; and/or is there any way around this?

Here's a little example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "You should only see this line, and not any other line."

function foo {
    false
    echo "The above line is false. Figure that one out, Plato."
}

bar=$(foo)

echo $bar
```

It prints both lines.
(Using `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`)

Comment: Wait, I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970663/why-doesnt-bash-flag-e-exit-when-a-subshell-fails?rq=1

Comment: but I have a later version of bash than the previous question answerer, does this mean bash has regressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference in handling of `-e` between subshells created with `(...)`, as in [Why doesn't bash flag -e exit when a subshell fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970663/why-doesnt-bash-flag-e-exit-when-a-subshell-fails?rq=1), and subshells created with command substitution `$(...)`, as in the OP.

According to the section `COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT` in the bash manual (and slightly confusingly):

> Subshells  spawned  to  execute  command substitutions inherit the value of the -e option from the parent shell.  When not in posix mode, bash clears the -e option in such subshells.

Regardless of the posix setting, the `-e` only applies to the subshell created for the purposes of command substitution. So:

```
$ set -e
# The subshell has -e cleared
$ echo $(false; echo foo)
foo
$ set -o posix
# Now the subshell has -e, so it terminates at `false`
$ echo $(false; echo foo)

$
```

Nonetheless, `-e` does apply to the execution of a command which *only sets a variable*. So

```
set -e
a=$(false)
```

will terminate the shell.

However, `-e` does not apply to individual commands in a function. In the case of

```
fail() {
  false
  echo "failed"
}
```

The return value of `fail` is 0 (i.e. success) because the `echo` (which was the last command executed) succeeded. Consequently

```
a=$(fail) && echo ok
```

will set `a` to `failed` and then print `ok`

Comment: so, what does that mean exactly? Is there a way to run a command, and store the response in a variable, but the script still to exit if that subcommand fails?

Comment: that's the solution I feared. I'm using a lot of command substitution in the script I'm working on, because bash seems to lack returning non-interger values. :\

Comment: @coiax Doesn't setting posix mode do this for you? The answer states that in posix mode, `-e` applies to subshells created for purposes of command execution. Or were you expecting the entire parent shell to exit when you get an error?

Comment: I guess the entire parent shell? Would using backticks be any different?

Comment: @coiax: No. Command substitution is command substitution. Why don't you try a question about your problem with non-integer values?

Comment: @coiax: I added some mumblage. Hope it helps. Lunchtime!

Comment: +1 for good answer and patient technical support. Believe the evidence in front of you! ;-> Good luck to all.

Comment: @rici Thanks for your help, this pretty much explains the effects I was seeing. We've now switched to a non-bash script anyway. :3