# set -e ignored in function when invoked in context where exit status is tested?

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to exit out of a shell function whenever any of the commands run in it fail using `set -e`

```
foo () (
    set -e
    echo $SHELLOPTS
    false
    echo set -e failed
)

echo test1:
foo
test $? -ne 0 && echo died

echo
echo test2:
foo && echo died
```

Here's the output I get using bash 4.2.37:

```
test1:
braceexpand:errexit:hashall:interactive-comments
died

test2:
braceexpand:errexit:hashall:interactive-comments
set -e failed
died
```

If `foo` is called as a simple command (**test1**), `foo` exits before the `echo` command, as I expect.  However, if called in a compound command (**test2**), the `set -e` seems to be ignored and execution continues past the failing command.

I know that with `-e` failures are ignored for all but the last element of a pipeline, but I don't expect that if a subshell is run as *part* of a pipeline that its `exiterr` status would be overridden especially if explicitly set.  Note that `SHELLOPTS` indicates that `errexit` is always set, even in the second test.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Diab

Comment: Unrelated, but `test $?` will always succeed. You probably mean something like `test $? -ne 0` instead.

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/34365186/1275160.  That seems broken.

Comment: @chepner : Thanks.  Over zealous editing on my part.  I'll fix it.

Comment: `set -e` isn't reliable in general: The rules it follows are too complex to make it easy to maintain a straightforward mental model. Unless none of the behaviors in BashFAQ #105 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) surprise you at all, it's better to do error-handling explicitly.

Comment: Just to note, this behavior is at least consistent across a wide range of shells (ignoring the fact that `$SHELLOPTS` is specific to `bash`); `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` all output "set -e failed" in addition to the three versions of `bash` (3.2, 4.3, 4.4) that I tried. It seems to be intentional, although a choice I don't quite understand.

Comment: BTW, I don't see a single pipeline anywhere in your question. What are they doing in the title?

Comment: ...on rereading, I assume  you're calling `foo && bar` a pipeline. It isn't; it's just a compound command (which sets the flag for tested exit status for `foo`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Agreed, the title was incorrect, but your new language is a bit broad, in that an actual pipeline doesn't exhibit the same behavior, i.e., `foo | cat` respects the `set -e`.

Comment: @DiabJerius, ...an actual pipeline's behavior depends on the value of the `pipefail` flag. That said, your example has nothing to do with `foo | cat`, so I don't understand how it relates to the intended question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,  I was presenting a context which I thought would not fit within the new scope of the title, unfortunately forgetting that the error status of a command in a pipeline is (as you pointed out) dependent upon the `pipefail` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Test 1

Use `set -E` (aka `set -o errtrace`) in addition to `set -e` if you want the behavior of `set -e` to apply even inside a function:

```
set -E -e

foo () (
    echo $SHELLOPTS
    false
    echo set -e failed
)

echo test1:
foo
test $? -ne 0 && echo died

echo
echo test2:
foo && echo died
```

Note, however, that triggers an **exit**, not a **return**, should the function fail. Thus, the output of this is something akin to:

```
test1:
braceexpand:errexit:errtrace:hashall:interactive-comments:xtrace
```

...with no further content, as the exit occurs immediately on the `false`.

#### Test 2

As for `foo && echo died`, because the exit status for `foo` is tested, the flag to disable `set -e` is enabled during its execution, so it's expected, defined behavior for this flag to have no effect.

#### Advice

The behavior of `set -e` is not intuitive. Before depending on it, be sure you fully understand all the examples of behavior given in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and consider also reading through [the excellent fvue writeup of error handling in bash](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling).

Comment: In the original code, **test1**  worked without `set -E`. It doesn't seem to improve things.

Comment: Sure. If test1 was a description of what you want, then your question is just a dupe of the one you posted as a comment. (It may "seem broken", but... well, that's the way `set -e` works. Is the way it works stupid? Yes! That's why at least half of the freenode #bash channel advises avoiding it).

Comment: Just trying to understand the subtleties.  The code in **test2** is what led to this question, so that's the case in which I'm interested.  Your description of why this is expected behavior is quite helpful.